# How to append value to a custom attribute using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I've "div.tile" elements. Each has a custom attribute "dist", like this:

```
<div class="tile" dist="dist-3"></div>
```

now I want to append a "dist-5" value to the attribute "dist". Like this:

```
<div class="tile" dist="dist-3 dist-5"></div>
```

How can I do this?

After searching, I found this:

```
$('.tile').each(function(){ this.dist += "dist-5"; })
```

But as you can guess, this won't work.

I'm looking for elegant way to do it besides `tile.attr('dist', tile.attr('dist')+' '+'dist-5')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) setter that takes a function as parameter

```
$('.tile').attr('dist', function (id, attr) {
    return attr + " dist-5";
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qn2FY/)

Comment: This is something like my un-elegant hack, as mentioned above. Thank you nevertheless